# Long contains many int

Tags: java

My exercise is to assigne many numbers to one long.
1. 17-bit number
2. 7-bit number
3. 17-bit number
4. 7-bit number
5. 13-bit number
6. 3-bit number

One function packs this 6 ints into one long
Second function read this 6 ints from one long and print information

When I compile this I get wrong numbers. ( like this )
Caller:      2012
Caller_zone: 92
Callee:      16398
Callee_zone: 123
Duration:    0
Tariff:      6

`

```
public class Problem_3_5{
public static void main(String[] args){
    info(encode(130999, 101, 7777, 99, 7000, 6));

}
public static long encode(int caller, int caller_zone,
                          int callee, int callee_zone,
                          int duration, int tariff) {
    long res = 0;
    long example = 0;

    //---1st---
    example = caller;
    res = res | example;
    res = res << 17;

    //---2nd---
    example = caller_zone;
    res = res | example;
    res = res << 7;

    //---3rd---
    example = callee;
    res = res | example;
    res = res << 17;

    //---4th---
    example = callee_zone;
    res = res | example;
    res = res << 7;

    //---5th---
    example = duration;
    res = res | example;
    res = res << 13;

    //---6th---
    example = tariff;
    res = res | example;

    //--END---
    return res;
    //---------------------------
}

public static void info(long res){
    //---TARIFF----
    long tariff = 0;
        tariff = (res & 7);
        res = res >>> 3;

    //---DURATION---
    long duration = 0;
        duration = (res & 8191);
        res = res >>> 13;

    //---CALLEE_ZONE---
    long callee_zone = 0;
        callee_zone = (res & 127);
        res = res >>> 7;

    //---CALLEE---
    long callee = 0;
        callee = (res & 131071);
        res = res >>> 17;

    //---CALLER_ZONE---
    long caller_zone = 0;
        caller_zone = (res & 127);

    //---CALLER---
    long caller = 0;
        caller = (res & 131071);

    //---Printing---

    System.out.println("Caller:      " + caller);
    System.out.println("Caller_zone: " + caller_zone);
    System.out.println("Callee:      " + callee);
    System.out.println("Callee_zone: " + callee_zone);
    System.out.println("Duration:    " + duration);
    System.out.println("Tariff:      " + tariff);
    //-----------------------------------------------   
}
```

}`

Comment: What makes you think they are wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but all that bit masking would be a lot easier to reason about if you used hex.

Comment: @shmosel binary would be best but hex or octal would be better than decimal.

Comment: @shmosel YMMV, but bit fiddling w/ base 10 is nuts. Maybe I'm just used to hex; it's only marginally less clear than binary, and much easier to deal with for 32-bit values. *shrug*

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah I guess you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The encoder allocates the wrong amount of bits for every item. For example:

```
//---1st---
example = caller;
res = res | example;
res = res << 17;
```

Well, let's first simplify that:

```
//---1st---
res = res | caller;
res = res << 17;
```

Since the shift is the last step, it allocates 17 bits for the *next* item. But 17 is the size of `caller`, not of the next item, caller_zone. So the sizes are wrong and things get mixed up.

It should look more like this, with the shift "before" writing in the new bits:

```
//---1st---
res |= caller;

//---2nd---
res <<= 7;
res |= caller_zone;

//---3rd---
res <<= 17;
res |= callee;

//---4th---
res <<= 7;
res |= callee_zone;

//---5th---
res <<= 13;
res |= duration;

//---6th---
res <<= 3;
res |= tariff;
```

Also, the decoder misses a shift. The shift pattern should be the "mirror" of the encoder, for obvious reasons, so it's fairly easy to check whether it "lines up". The masks are a bit harder to check, especially in decimal which obscures the true value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be shortened a lot by doing it like this:

```
public static long encode(int caller, int caller_zone,
                          int callee, int callee_zone,
                          int duration, int tariff) {
    return ((caller      & 0x1FFFFL/*17 bits*/) << 47)
         + ((caller_zone & 0x0007FL/* 7 bits*/) << 40)
         + ((callee      & 0x1FFFFL/*17 bits*/) << 23)
         + ((callee_zone & 0x0007FL/* 7 bits*/) << 16)
         + ((duration    & 0x01FFFL/*13 bits*/) <<  3)
         +  (tariff      & 0x00007L/* 3 bits*/);
}
public static int[] decode(long res) {
    return new int[] {
        (int) (res >> 47) & 0x1FFFF/*17 bits*/, // caller
        (int) (res >> 40) & 0x0007F/* 7 bits*/, // caller_zone
        (int) (res >> 23) & 0x1FFFF/*17 bits*/, // callee
        (int) (res >> 16) & 0x0007F/* 7 bits*/, // callee_zone
        (int) (res >>  3) & 0x01FFF/*13 bits*/, // duration
        (int)  res        & 0x00007/* 3 bits*/  // tariff
    };
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decode(encode(130999, 101, 7777, 99, 7000, 6))));
```

*Output*

```
[130999, 101, 7777, 99, 7000, 6]
```

One trick applied here, in the `encode` method, is the `&` AND-operator with a `long` literal, implicitly widening the `int` value to `long` *before* `<<` left-shifting the value. The extra benefit of doing bit-masking in the `encode` method is that too-large inputs are "truncated" to the number of supported bits, thereby preventing overflow.

Also, the `>>` signed-extending shift-operator could be changed to the `>>>` unsigned shift-operator, but it doesn't matter, because the bit-mask is applied *after* the shift, so sign bit is discarded anyway.